# Does Mount and Blade Warband have cheats to allow me to besiege a castle on my own? If so, how can I enable and use these?

Tags: cheats, mount-and-blade-warband

I love to play Mount and Blade solo. I'm getting to the point where my character can win 1 v 75 battles without having to retreat. I'd like to be able to try and see just how far I can get with taking castles, but there's one problem:

There's a minimum party size of 5 or so when you wish to besiege a castle. No problem, I guess, I can hire 5 guys at a nearby town, start the siege and build the entire tower on my own whilst fending off bandits. But then it turns out you need to actually have like 5 people in order to even be allowed to start an attack during a siege.

I checked menus.txt of the game's files, and it seems there's several "cheat" options in there to forcibly start a siege. However, checking a [wiki](http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Cheats) for the game does not list menu options as cheats... so how can I trigger those cheat actions?

Comment: Your changes have addressed the concerns raised with your post, so I've cast a vote to reopen your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Looking at the source code](https://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php?topic=111706.0), the cheat menu doesn't actually allow you to attack a castle on your own. You can start a siege on your own via the cheat menu, but you will not be able to perform the actual attack. For that, you need at least 3 soldiers:

```
  ("castle_lead_attack",
   [
     (neg|troop_is_wounded, "trp_player"),
     (ge, "$g_siege_method", 1),
     (gt, "$g_friend_fit_for_battle", 3),
     (store_current_hours, ":cur_hours"),
     (ge, ":cur_hours", "$g_siege_method_finish_hours"),
   ],
   "Lead your soldiers in an assault.",
```

---

```
  ("attack_stay_back",
   [
     (ge, "$g_siege_method", 1),
     (gt, "$g_friend_fit_for_battle", 3),
     (store_current_hours, ":cur_hours"),
     (ge, ":cur_hours",  "$g_siege_method_finish_hours"),
     ],
   "Order your soldiers to attack while you stay back...",
```

**So, what we can conclude is that this is not possible without modding.**

What you can do, in this case, is edit the menus.txt file. **Make a backup first!**

```
mno_castle_start_siege  13 1073742365 3 144115188075856273 54 -1 541 3 144115188075856273 54 648518346341351424 2190 3 1224979098644774912 144115188075856787 432345564227567630 2147483678 2 1224979098644774912 0 2147483678 2 144115188075856786 1 1 2 936748722493063353 648518346341351424 32 2 72057594037927936 5 4 0 541 3 144115188075856273 0 3 2133 2 72057594037927942 1 5 0 2133 2 72057594037927942 0 3 0  Besiege_the_{reg6?town:castle}.
```

edit to

```
mno_castle_start_siege  13 1073742365 3 144115188075856273 54 -1 541 3 144115188075856273 54 648518346341351424 2190 3 1224979098644774912 144115188075856787 432345564227567630 2147483678 2 1224979098644774912 0 2147483678 2 144115188075856786 1 1 2 936748722493063353 648518346341351424 32 2 72057594037927936 0 4 0 541 3 144115188075856273 0 3 2133 2 72057594037927942 1 5 0 2133 2 72057594037927942 0 3 0  Besiege_the_{reg6?town:castle}.
```

That's a one character change - a 5 into a 0, and it corresponds to changing the 5 into a 0 here:

```
  ("castle_start_siege",
   [
       (this_or_next|party_slot_eq, "$g_encountered_party", slot_center_is_besieged_by, -1),
       (             party_slot_eq, "$g_encountered_party", slot_center_is_besieged_by, "p_main_party"),
       (store_relation, ":reln", "$g_encountered_party_faction", "fac_player_supporters_faction"),
       (lt, ":reln", 0),
       (lt, "$g_encountered_party_2", 1),
       (call_script, "script_party_count_fit_for_battle","p_main_party"),
       (gt, reg(0), 5),
       (try_begin),
         (party_slot_eq, "$g_encountered_party", slot_party_type, spt_town),
         (assign, reg6, 1),
       (else_try),
         (assign, reg6, 0),
       (try_end),
       ],
   "Besiege the {reg6?town:castle}.",
```

You're setting the "party_count_fit_for_battle" requirement from "more than 5" to "more than 0". This will allow you to start the siege on your own.

As for actually allowing the siege: Menus.txt again, this time for `mno_castle_lead_attack`:

```
mno_castle_lead_attack  5 2147485156 1 360287970189639680 30 2 144115188075856225 1 32 2 144115188075856836 3 2270 1 1224979098644774912 30 2 1224979098644774912 144115188075856229  Lead_your_soldiers_in_an_assault.
```

This needs to be edited to

```
mno_castle_lead_attack  5 2147485156 1 360287970189639680 30 2 144115188075856225 1 32 2 144115188075856836 -1 2270 1 1224979098644774912 30 2 1224979098644774912 144115188075856229  Lead_your_soldiers_in_an_assault.
```

This changes the "3" for the `(gt, "$g_friend_fit_for_battle", 3),` which validates if you have more 3 soldiers into a "-1" - "at least 0 soldiers". With these two changes, you should be able to (theoretically) besiege a castle on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is late, but to activate the menu, press the tilde key <kbd>`</kbd> and the shift key together. This should open a black bar on the screen.  Type in Cheatmenu, then press enter.  When you go to a town/castle, you should be able to scroll down to an option Cheat : Besiege Castle.

Comment: It's late, but that doesn't stop me from trying to tonight =D

Comment: The cheatmenu doesn't allow you to actually besiege the castle without getting 5 men.